# The statistics of queries are not available v$sql

Tags: oracle, toad

I am using TOAD 9.5.0.31 as my Oracle client. But statistics for the queries executed using TOAD are not visible in v$sql. I am using the following query to get the statistics

```
  select *  
    from v$sql v Where v.PARSING_SCHEMA_NAME = '<schemaname>'
     And module like 'TOAD%' and SUBSTR (V.LAST_LOAD_TIME, 1, 10) = '2016-08-10' 
   Order by V.LAST_LOAD_TIME desc
```

The Oracle document says there can be a delay of 5 seconds to update the statistics, but even after 5 seconds it is not visible. What is the reason.

There is no error in the query.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it starts with `TOAD` ? Try using `'%TOAD%'` and see if you get any results

Comment: Your query works for me ("TOAD Freeware 12.9.0.71"). Maybe it's the other 2 conditions (schema name or Last_Load_Time). You should try without those.

Comment: Strange it works for me as well. Query is absolutely fine.

Comment: Just checking - you did replace the string '<schemaname>' with your actual schema name, right? As in 'SCOTT' or 'HR'. And you typed those in all-caps? 'scott' will not work, it must be 'SCOTT'.